# Build fails after 2 times build of the application in flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, visual-studio-code, filesystemexception

After building my flutter application in VS code, I successfully run the app, everything works fine. But after 2 or more times of restart of the application, whenever I run my code again, the build gets failed. This is the error pops up.

```
Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'J:\flutter_projects\webdoc\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\assets\images\background.png', path = 'J:\flutter_projects\webdoc\assets\images\background.png' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        10.2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

When first time this error has occured, I cut all the files from the current directory and copied into other directory, and then it works again fine. But even now after running 2 or 3 times again the error pops up. Is there any fix available to this problem?

**I tried deleting the .vscode, rebuilding again, but still its the same!!**

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I have to run "flutter clean" every time before running/building the app, which is really a pain. Awaiting a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a file permissions related issue. try to copy the files using command line. you shall receive similar error.

> copy J:\flutter_projects\webdoc\assets\images\background.png J:\flutter_projects\webdoc\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\assets\images\background.png

Now check if you have necessary permissions on the destination directory/file or the destination file/directory is not read only.

> Blockquote

Reference : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49874

Answer (score 0):

Stop running your application clear all recents applications then try again.

If this do not work try unistall your application, reinstall applications.

If these also not works , run 'flutter clean' then 'flutter pub get' .

These will clear temp files and add only neccessary files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved by turning of 
Windows Controlled Folder Access[Steps to turn of windows cont](http://Windows%20Controlled%20Folder%20Access)

Comment: its already off. even when i checked both modes, the error still exists

Comment: yes, whenever I try running command flutter clean and building it, it works. Its a temporary fix that works, not a standard one.

Comment: this does not help.  Windows Controlled Folder Access is already turned off.

Comment: Broken link too.