# How to solve flutter error (OS Error: Access Denied, errno = 5 )?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to learn Flutter. My problem is that when I run my flutter project for the first time it runs and installs successfully on the device, but if I disconnect the device and rerun the project it gives an error.

I am trying to display images in my app.

When I run `flutter clean` or `flutter clean build` or `flutter clean cache` and rerun the project it does not gives the error, then after disconnecting the device the problem occurs again.
I searched google for hours but it did not help me.
this the the error:

```
Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'G:\Flutter 
   Projects\my_practice_7\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\images\image.png', 
path = 'G:\Flutter Projects\my_practice_7\images\image.png' 
(OS Error: Access is denied. 
, errno = 5)
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'G:\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
```

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476], locale en-GB)
  • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at G:\Android\flutter
  • Framework revision 27321ebbad (7 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
  • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
  • Dart version 2.7.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
  • Android SDK at G:\Android\Sdk
  • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
  • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
  • ANDROID_HOME = G:\Android\Sdk\
  • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
  • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
  • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
  • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
  • Dart plugin version 191.8593
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
  • VS Code at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
  • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
  • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

  • No issues found!
```

Comment: Is there another process open that has that file open?  Silly suggestion, bu try re-booting?

Comment: @OldProgrammer No there is'nt.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. I have to run "flutter clean" every time before running/building the app. Awaiting permanent solution. 

This is also a related post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450634/build-fails-after-2-times-build-of-the-application-in-flutter

Comment: @SureshKumar this is very anoying. everthing that came to my mind  I did but no luck.  I tried chenging the permission and owners etc 

Comment: I am also facing the same issues

Answer (score 2):

Don't copy `.packages` over from one machine to another. (It should be in `.gitignore` if using git.)

Instead, run flutter packages get on the mac, and it will recreate `.packages`.

(Don't copy `.flutter-plugins either`.)

1. Delete `.packages`
2. Delete `pubspec.lock`
3. Run below command shown in image
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the ransomware shield that prevented the files to be accessed and it worked perfectly, but there must be a solution without putting your files at risk

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a file permissions related issue. try to copy the files using command line. you shall receive similar error.

> copy "G:\Flutter Projects\my_practice_7\images\image.png" "G:\Flutter Projects\my_practice_7\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\images\image.png"

Now check if you have necessary permissions on the destination directory/file or the destination file/directory is not read only.

Reference : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49874

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the app on the device or perform wipe data on the emulator then run the application. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I copied the entire content of pubspec.lock and then deleted it.. After that I created new file in the same path with the same file name which is pubspec.lock and paste the content that I already copied.. run "flutter pub get" and it should absolutely work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was my `Avast antivirus`  blocking access.

I have allowed `flutter` to have access and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file from its current location and made a run to make flutter re-build the file again and it worked.